# Installing a printer without the CD

Tags: installation, drivers, printer, compact-disc

Is there a way of installing a printer without the installation CD.
I'm using windows and the printer is an hp.

Comment: As the answers are indicating, this depends on the printer! You need to be more specific!

Comment: @Shinrai And on the Operating System you're running

Comment: @BloodPhilia Well, to be fair, if it's an old enough printer (which is possible if he no longer has the disc) then drivers may not be available online anywhere anymore, at which point the operating system is probably irrelevant.  (But you're right of course.)

Comment: also beware that HP is notorious for bundling excessive amounts of software with the downloads. One package I encountered was nearly 500mb for drivers and full suite.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, download the driver from the manufacturer website. Or, if it is your day, you might be able to "choose" your printer from the ones that come with Windows (assuming you are running windows).

Answer (score 1):

If you have Windows Vista/7, most printer drivers are already in the OS. It should work. You can also go on the printer manufacturer's website to download its driver and install it.

Answer (score 0):

Search the Printer's driver in the HP Website: http://welcome.hp.com/country/us/en/support.html

You need to specify your printer Model on the search box.